# How use BeautifulSoup in Synology DS213+

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, nas, synology

i'm trying to use BeautifulSoup on my NAS, that is the model in the title, but i am not able to install it, with the `ipkg list` there isn't a package named BeautifulSoup.
On my NAS i have this version of python:

```
Python 2.5.6 (r256:88840, Feb 16 2012, 08:51:29) 
[GCC 3.4.3 20041021 (prerelease)] on linux2
```

So i think i have to use the version 3 of Beautiful soup, so i have two question:

1) anyone knows how i can install it?

2) if i can't install this module i can import directly the BeautifulSoup.py file directly in my script? if yes how i can do?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

In this case I suppose that you can't even install pip to manage your Python dependencies. One way of doing so would be to download the source from http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/download//3.x/, download the tarball for your preferred version. Once done, unzip it cd into the folder and type:

```
$ python setup.py install
```

Comment: BeautifulSoup 3 is just one file: `BeautifulSoup.py` it is enough to put it in a directory with the script.

Answer (score 0):

You can if you install python3 from the package manager:

```
ashton@NASty:~/bin/three/$  pip install beautifulsoup4 -- user
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in 
/volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (4.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>=1.2 in 
/volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from beautifulsoup4) (1.9.2)
```